# Indexers in generic Interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

```
public interface IRepository <T>  where T : EntityBase
{
    T FindBy(object key);
    void Add(T item);
    T this[object key] { get; set; }
    void Remove(T item); 
}
```

This is the code sample of a generic Repository interface which was given by the author of the book "Domain-Driven-Design .NET C#". Without explanation the author puts an indexer in the interface `T this[object key] { get; set; }` where the object key is the objects ID (in terms of identity across the system). The author states that the indexer is put there for emphasizing that a repository should emulate a collection of objects in memory. So my question is: Are there any benefits in putting an indexer in an interface? Any links, videos, books, tutorials would help me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "instead of IEnumerable or List"? Can you show these alternatives to having an indexer?

Comment: Using an indexer and returning an `IEnumerable` or a `List` are different things, given that `T` isn't a collection. I want to use an indexer when given a known key, I can retrieve it's value, or given a key set it's value. Perhaps elaborate on what you mean instead of asking for a tutorial.

Comment: I am sorry for irelavent info. Did not mean to put IEnumerable or List in that context. I got lost in translation. I will edit the question. Thank you for patience.

Comment: Eh, if you need an indexer you put one. I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

> The author states that the indexer is put there for emphasizing that a
>   repository should emulate a collection of objects in memory.

I honestly never heard of this concept. I saw repository pattern implementation on a lot of projects and we never used indexer there. In fact indexer will serve to get item by ID, which would duplicate your `T FindBy(object key);`.

So, my summary: repository in most of cases indeed provides access to a collection of objects, but I don't see any value in adding indexer to it. I'd rather focus on transactions/queries, needed for your application.

---

I usually implement generic `IRepository<T>` with `BaseRepository : IRepository<T>` and then implement specific repositories `UsersRepository : BaseRepository<User>, IUsersRepository` where `IUsersRepository` interface contains specifc methods for user queries and commands.

Answer (score 0):

An indexer is used in this case to retrieve an object given it's key (not its index in the collection). Out of the standard generic interfaces in System.Collections.Generic the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is the one that contains that functionality. However, that interface contains a lot more functionality that is not naturally exposed by a repository.

Sure, it would be possible to implement those other methods, but they would not be efficient. And offering non-efficient APIs is a sure way to invite the user of the API to write inefficient code.

Comment: "Out of the standard generic interfaces the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is the one that contains that functionality." - depending on what you call "standard generic interfaces", lots of other interfaces offer indexers, too.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper edited and made it a bit more clear that I meant the System.Collections.Generic interfaces.

Comment: Then what about [`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? It has an indexer, too.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper See my edited answer, that indexer is used on index, not on the key of the object.

Answer (score 0):

> The author states that the indexer is put there for emphasizing that a repository should emulate a collection of objects in memory.

This sounds like a reasonable rationale. By the word "emphasizing", it points to one important aspect: The indexer does not necessarily add any functionality, it can also be used simply to improve readability of the resulting code.

Assuming some object has a property named `Resources` of type `IRepository<Something>`, without the indexer, specific items can be retrieved only as follows:

```
var theItem = myObject.Resources.FindBy(someKey);
```

With an indexer, the following is possible, as well:

```
var theItem = myObject.Resources[someKey];
```

To some extent, this is a matter of personal preference, but the second version might be more intuitively recognizeable as a mere retrieval from something like a list, rather than an arbitrary parametrized method call.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any benefits in putting an indexer in an interface?

This is subjective. If you find more meaningful locate objects by some *key*, *why not?*

The main issue when using indexers is **they can be overloaded**. While your interface defines an indexer to get objects *by id* (where the *id* is `object`... I would turn object id into a generic type...), following the proposed pattern, it might happen that you lose the meaning of the indexer if you define more than an indexer than *the one that retrieves domain objects by their identifiers*.

For example:

```
T this[object key] { get; set; }
T this[T someObject] { get; set; }
T this[int whoKnowsWhatIsIntegerHere] { get; set; }
```

At the end of the day, it's up to you to implement indexers and it won't emphasize more or less using them in terms of implementing repositories in the right way: **repositories are fine when they mediate between the domain and the data mapper to translate domain objects to data and vice versa.**. That is, it's not about what name have their methods or if they look like `IList<T>` or not...

Working like a collection doesn't mean *look like a collection*...